# Trouble populating a combobox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I've got a model class like so:

```
public class AttributesModel
    {
        public SortOrder SortBy { get; set; }

        public enum SortOrder
        {
            Unsorted,
            Ascending,
            Descending
        }

        public AttributesModel(string field)
        {
            Field = field;
        }
    }
```

And a DataGrid which contains a Combobox as one of the columns, like so:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="False" Header="Order">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AttributesModel}" DisplayMemberPath="SortBy" SelectedValuePath="SortBy" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=AttributesModel}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

The class containing the DataGrid also has the following as the constructor:

```
DataContext = this;
itemsSource = new ObservableCollection<AttributesModel>(parentDatabaseTable.ListFields.Select(f => new AttributesModel(f)));
```

For some reason, all the fields in my DataGrid are populating except for the combobox.  Please note that I haven't included code for the other fields in the model class, or columns in the DataGrid for simplicity and readability.  They all get populated successfully, except for the combobox column.  Any ideas?

Comment: So it looks like you're binding `ComboBox` to a property `AttributesModel` that *isn't* an `IEnumerable`, is that right?

Comment: The enum contained in it actually. I've got other fields too, which it binds to with no problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Matt's answer above should work in theory, but if you'd prefer not to make a wrapper, you could use this xaml based code. It will need your `Enums` to be contained in root namespace instead of nested in a class but other than that, you can just create an `ObjectDataProvider` `StaticResource` on top of your `Enum` and bind that to your `ComboBox`.

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestApplication.DatabaseTable"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestApplication"
             mc:Ignorable="d" Width="Auto" Height="Auto">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ObjectDataProvider ObjectType="{x:Type sys:Enum}" MethodName="GetValues" x:Key="SortOrderProvider">
            <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
                <x:Type TypeName="local:SortOrder" />
            </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
        </ObjectDataProvider>
    </UserControl.Resources>
        <DataGrid x:Name="grid" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource}" AutoGenerateColumns="True">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Order" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource SortOrderProvider}}" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding SortBy, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 2):

An `ItemsSource` has to be a collection. You `AttributeModel` isn't a collection.

If you want to bind options of an enum, I've used this in the past:

```
public class EnumWrapper<T> where T:struct
{
    private List<T> values;

    public List<T> Values
    {
        get { return values; }
        set { values = value; }
    }

    public EnumWrapper()
    {
        // Note: Annoyingly, you can't restrict T to an Enum, so we have to check at runtime!
        Type type = typeof(T);
        if (!type.IsEnum)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Type must be an enum");
        }
        Array a = Enum.GetValues(type);
        values = a.Cast<T>().ToList();
    }
}
```

Which you can use like this:

```
 EnumWrapper<SortOrder> SortOptions = new EnumWrapper<SortOrder>();
```

Then you can expose that as a property and use it as your `ItemsSource`

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding SortOptions}" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SortBy}"/>
```

Comment: What about the properties I've set for the ComboBox? Are those valid?

Comment: @DotNET: I've updated by answer, assuming the DataContext is already an instance of your `AttributesModel` class and `SortOptions` is a property of type `EnumWrapper<SortOrder>`

Comment: @MattBurland I think your EnumWrapper constructor code has a typo in it. It isn't taking any Type parameter but your example passes it in. I'm also guessing that you meant to write "Annoyingly, you CAN'T restrict T..." :)  +1 for the effort though.

Comment: @Maverik: Yep, I had a previous version that took a type parameter, then I realized that I didn't need it.